# Slider using css and javascript

Tags: html, css, slider

I have this slider, it works. but I need to see arrows under blocks as it on image. How can I do that?

[image]

In this image arrows under blocks.
css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slider__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  transition: transform 0.6s ease;
}

.slider__item {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  max-width: 50%;
}

.slider__control {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 50px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.slider__control:hover,
.slider__control:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: 0;
  opacity: .9;
}

.slider__control_left {
  left: 0;
}

.slider__control_right {
  right: 0;
}

.slider__control::before {
  content: '';
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: transparent no-repeat center center;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.slider__control_left::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M5.25 0l-4 4 4 4 1.5-1.5-2.5-2.5 2.5-2.5-1.5-1.5z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.slider__control_right::before {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' fill='%23fff' viewBox='0 0 8 8'%3E%3Cpath d='M2.75 0l-1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5-2.5 2.5 1.5 1.5 4-4-4-4z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
}

.slider__item>div {
  line-height: 250px;
  font-size: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

html:

```
  <div class="slider">
    <div class="slider__wrapper">
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: orange;">1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: green;">2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: violet;">3</div>
      </div>
      <div class="slider__item">
        <div style="height: 250px; background: coral;">4</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="slider__control slider__control_left" href="#" role="button"></a>
    <a class="slider__control slider__control_right slider__control_show" href="#" role="button"></a>    
  </div>
```

I need to see arrows as they are on image, under my blocks. Slider works, I will not add js code, I just try to do `css` part of it. Help me, if you can.

Comment: added image from link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout the updated pen here: https://codepen.io/thecenteno/pen/BbobGN

I updated some CSS but what was also important was adding a wrapper around the controls to have more control over it.  The most important items were:

```
/* Added: */

.slider__controls {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row;
}
.slider__control {
  /* Added: */
  border-radius: 50%;

  /* Updated: */
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 50px;

  /* The Same: */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.5;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  /*
    REMOVED: transform: translateY(-50%);
  */
}
```

From this starting point, you can add different styles to it. Flex works great when the targeted elements have a parent div.

Comment: Excuse me, can I ask one more question?

Comment: in this slider https://jsfiddle.net/13fowgvt/2/ I need to scroll just 2 blocks, but when I do that I can not see first block. instead of this I see white space. I have increased value from 100 to 200. How can I solve that?